# How to add multiple object types to elasticsearch using jdbc river?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm using the jdbc river to successfully add one object type, "contacts", to elasticsearch.  How can I add another contact type with different fields?  I'd like to add "companies" as well.

What I have is below. Do I need to do a separate PUT statement? If I do, no new data appears to be added to elasticsearch.

```
PUT /_river/projects_river/_meta
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "index" : {
        "index" : "ALL",
        "type" : "project",
        "bulk_size" : 500,
        "max_bulk_requests" : 1,
        "autocommit": true
        },
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "poll" : "30s",
        "strategy" : "poll",
        "url" : "jdbc:sqlserver://connectionstring",
        "user":"username","password":"password",
        "sql" : "select ContactID as _id, * from Contact"
        }
}
```

Also, when search returns results, how can I tell if they are of type contact or company?  Right now they all have a type of "jdbc", and changing that in the code above throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with inserting several columns to your sql query.

Like `ContactID AS _id` you can also define `indexName AS _index` and `indexType AS _type` in your sql query.

Also, if you need another river, add rivers with different `_river` types.

In your case such as,

```
PUT /_river/projects_river2/_meta + Query ....
PUT /_river/projects_river3/_meta + Query ....
```

Comment: End result I'd like to be able to do a single search to search through multiple sql tables.  Some tables will be type contact, some of type company, etc up to about 30 types.  Do I need a new River for each?

Comment: Yes. For each table-type pair you need an extra river.

Comment: Syntax changed for the river plugin.  Most examples on the web have the old syntax. Once I realized this and referenced the updated official documentation your answer was much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else who stumbles across this, please see official documentation for syntax first: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/How-bulk-indexing-isused-by-the-JDBC-river

Here's the final put statement I used:

```
PUT /_river/contact/_meta
{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url":"connectionstring",
        "user":"username",
        "password":"password",
        "sql":"select ContactID as _id,* from Contact",
        "poll": "5m",
        "strategy": "simple",
        "index": "contact", 
        "type": "contact" 
    }       
}
```